# Is there way to replace an element in a numpy array with its index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have the following numpy array

```
 a = np.array(([4,5,6],[8,5,4]))
 
 Out[15]: 
 array([[4, 5, 6],
        [8, 5, 4]])
```

**Question:** Is there a pythonic way to conditionally replace elements in the array with a number from their index value?  For example, how could I replace all the even numbers with their row number?  I can accomplish this rather clumsily with a separate array of just row numbers as follows.

```
b = np.arange(a.shape[0])      
c = np.stack([b] * a.shape[1])
rownum = c.T 
# I think that maybe rownum can be replaced by broadcasting b? but I can't get it to work.   
a[a % 2 == 0] = rownum[a % 2 == 0]
```

I was wondering if there was a more direct/pythonic way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
w = np.where(a%2 == 0) #(array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 2, 0, 2]))
a[w] = w[0]
```

It returns the indices where the condition is `True` separated by axis, in this case, rows and columns.

---

A pretty similar approach would be using [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
w = np.nonzero(a%2 == 0)
a[w] = w[0]
```

Note: following the documentation, `nonzero` should be preferred over `where` in this case.

Comment: thanks!  if i wanted to set a criteria as to what rows to search through would that also be possible with np.nonzero?  So for example if I only wanted to search the even rows or row numbers such that the row number%x = y?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
a = np.where(a % 2 == 0, np.fromfunction(lambda r,c: r, a.shape, dtype=a.dtype),
    a)
```

Steps:

- `np.fromfunction(...)` - an array containing values to replace.
- `a` - original values.
- `a % 2 == 0` - selection criterion - from which source array take the value
  for the current element.

The result is:

```
array([[0, 5, 0],
       [1, 5, 1]])
```

Comment: thanks!  would you mind elaborating what the lambda is doing?

Comment: The lambda is a function to be called by *np.fromfunction*.
It receives 2 arguments: row and column (indices of the element in question)
and returns the row index.
So in the array - result of *np.fromfunction* - all elements in row *0*
are filled with *0*, elements in row *1* with *1* and so on.